# Restrict Outside scroll when Bootstrap modal is opened

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="modal  mt-5p" role="dialog" [ngStyle]="{'display':IONotes}">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md mt-0px width-70p">
    <div class="modal-content" style="height:500px">
      <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#51b8f2;color:white;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="IONotesClose()">&times;</button>
        <h5 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center">
          <strong>Intra-operative Notes</strong>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <label style="margin-left: -15%;">Surgery Type :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <label>{{M_SurgeryType}}</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5" style="margin-left: 6%;">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <label style="font-size: 13px;">Surgery Procedure :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <label style="font-size: 13px;margin-left: -72%;">{{surgeryprocedureName}}</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-left: -16%;">
              <button mat-raised-button type="button" *ngIf="removedOtNotes.length != 0" style="margin-left: 40%; background-color:#3dbb96; color:aliceblue;font-family: 'Proxima Nova Semibold';border-radius: 9px;" (click)="ViewunselectedOtNotes()" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add IO notes">View unselected Ot Notes</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1" style="margin-left: 5%;">
              <button mat-raised-button type="button" *ngIf="!IsDischarge" style="background-color:#3dbb96; color:aliceblue;font-family: 'Proxima Nova Semibold';border-radius: 9px;margin-top: 1%;" (click)="AddIoNotes()" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add IO notes">Add IO notes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ml-1p heightAuto-350px ml-1p position-sticky">

          <table #IONotestable  mat-table  [dataSource]="IntraoperativeNotesSource" class="custom-table withoutbackgroung search-table table-bordered"
                 cdkDropList
                 [cdkDropListData]="IntraoperativeNotesSource"
                  (cdkDropListDropped)="dropTable($event)">

            <ng-container matColumnDef="SNo">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="width-3p">S.No</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index" cdkDragHandle>{{i+1}}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Description">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="width-40p">Description</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let id = index" (mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()" contenteditable="true" (keyup)="changeIODesc(id,'OTNotesDescription',$event,element);">{{element.OTNotesDescription}} </td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Value">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="width-20p">Value</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let id = index" [attr.contenteditable]="element.UserInputType !== 'None'" (keyup)="changeInputValue(id,'GivenInputValue',$event,element);">
                <div *ngIf="element.UserInputType == 'User selection'">
                  <mat-select (selectionChange)="changeInputValues($event,element)" placeholder="Select">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let InputValue of element.InputValue" [value]="InputValue">{{InputValue}}</mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </div>
              </td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Others">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Others</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let id = index;">{{element.Others}} </td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Action">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
                <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove" (click)="removeDesc(i)" style="color: red;">delete</mat-icon> </button>
              </td>
              <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> </td>
            </ng-container>
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="IntraoperativeNotesColumns;sticky: true"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: IntraoperativeNotesColumns"
                  
                cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="row"></tr>
          </table>
        </div>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Above I shared my Bootstrap Modal code, I need to restrict the outside scroll it as shown in the picture once the Modal is opened i need to restrict the outside scroll on the right side.i have tried by giving overflow hidden property for modal content but its not working.Can Anyone tell how to fix this issue, Thanks In Advance

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jppP0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle `overflow:hidden` class on `body` when modal is toggled.

Example:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

onModelOpen() {
 //Add hide-scroll class when modal is opened
 this.document.body.classList.add('hide-scroll');
}

onModelClose() {
 //Remove hide-scroll class when modal is closed
 this.document.body.classList.remove('hide-scroll');
}
```

CSS

```
.hide-scroll {
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro Its working fine, Your are adding a class to the body while opening the Modal am I right bro, but i Tried with inline css to the Modal but it not worked, can you explain why its not working

Comment: Can we Restrict outside clicks of the Modal

Comment: That's a body scroll you have to hide it from body itself, For restricting outside clicks you can set `data-backdrop="static"` on modal [Example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#static-backdrop)